# Angular class variable loses value

Tags: angular

Using Angular2, I have an http.get as follows:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost/Authenticated/Token', loginData, options).subscribe(function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    if (data.status === 200) {
        this.response = data.json();
        this.access_token = this.response.access_token;
        alert(this.access_token);
    }
});
```

The value of this.access_token is being set correctly at runtime. But it loses value once the method is over. I am trying to use it somewhere else in a method but it says undefined.

**EDIT:**

Here is the method that is attached to a trigger on a button, that I call after I see the response from the previous method:

```
getBlogEntries() {
    alert(this.access_token);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.access_token);

    let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
    });

    if (this.access_token) {
        this.http.get('http://localhost/Authenticated/BlogEntries/', options).subscribe(result => {
            this.blogEntries = result.json().Data;
            console.log(this.blogEntries);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The question may be *when*. When are you using it somewhere else in the method? The http calls are async, so if you are immediately checking for the value in another part of the code, it won't be set yet.

Comment: I am checking after I see the response.

Comment: Can you add the code for that to your question?

Comment: @DeborahK yes sure, please check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost/Authenticated/Token', loginData, options).subscribe(function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    if (data.status === 200) {
        this.response = data.json();
        this.access_token = this.response.access_token;
        alert(this.access_token);
    }
}.bind(this));
```

It should resolve your issue.

### One more alternative if you code in ECMA 6.0:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost/Authenticated/Token', loginData, options).subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
        if (data.status === 200) {
            this.response = data.json();
            this.access_token = this.response.access_token;
            alert(this.access_token);
        }
    });
```

Comment: wow that worked! Why did it work though, what does the bind do at the end and why need it?

Comment: In javascript every function has its own scope so "this" always refer to that function scope. Means if you try to bind any value over "this" then that value will not be available outside function scope. Here you were trying to access that value outside the function scope so we used bind to pass parent function scope to the success callback.